# why do we need interface when we have abstract class?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need for Abstract Class as well as Interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322945/need-for-abstract-class-as-well-as-interface)

why do we need interface when we have abstract class ?

Answer : The only purpose for having interface is to achieve Multiple inheritance

Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: `interfaces` favour simplicity. Using them ensures you are only importing an API description, not state or functionality (until we have virtual extensions on interfaces ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Favour implements over extends.

Implementing an interface is more flexible that extending an abstract class. You can only extend a single class but you can implement many interfaces.

Comment: @Vincent: so you confirm the OP's opinion ("The only purpose for having interface is to be able to implement several of them"), right?

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of similar questions here on SO.

[Why is programming to abstract classes instead of interfaces wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904455/why-is-programming-to-abstract-classes-instead-of-interfaces-wrong/9904483#9904483)

I've answered here on the pros and cons of each, you might want to check it out.